# Why doesn't my desktop saved image appear on my html website?

Tags: html

I wrote this short code (taking one example from a website), I wanted my desktop saved image to appear on my HTML website (‪C:\Users\chan tien fatt\Pictures\homework4.jpg) All of the example images appears but the one I've put doesn't appear at all...  This is what turns out when I run my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax9wc.jpg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Image Gallery</h2>
<h4>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h4>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
      <img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
      <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="‪C:\Users\chan tien fatt\Pictures\homework4.jpg">
      <img src="‪C:\Users\chan tien fatt\Pictures\homework4.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div style="padding:6px;">
  <p>This example use media queries to re-arrange the images on different screen sizes: for screens larger than 700px wide, it will show four images side by side, for screens smaller than 700px, it will show two images side by side. For screens smaller than 500px, the images will stack vertically (100%).</p>
  <p>You will learn more about media queries and responsive web design later in our CSS Tutorial.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points that I'd like to point out to you in general-

1. Notice how your src contains 'chan tien fatt'. If you try to cd such a directory, it'll throw an error due to too many arguments. Try to have no spaces in your directory names or enclose that directory's name in inverted commas when you're making use of it, like so-
   C://Users/'chan tien fatt'/Pictures/homework4.jpg
   Space in names = bad.
2. Websites are made to be on the internet, so you better start practicing good habits. Make yourself a folder called images or assets in the same directory as your project, and use src="./assets/myimg.png" or something like that. That'll help you in the long run. Also, look into __dirname on the internet too.
3. I see some backward slashes on the directory name. Though that's correct windows syntax, you might want to replace it by forward slashes on your HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem: right-click on image, and open with web browser. Copy the URL and past it in to HTML Document. There, you should be good-to-go!

**Hint :** In your project , Just change the link to `file:///C:/Users/chan%20tien%20fatt/Pictures/homework4.jpg`

But why ?

1. Computer don't understand spaces, So we change it to `%20`
2. Type `file:///` before the link
3. Change `\` to `/`